# Apache Synapse SVN checkout error

Tags: apache, svn, apache-synapse

I am getting an error when I checkout the Apache Synapse source from the SVN repository. This is the command I used to checkout:

> svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/synapse/tags/2.1.0 Apache-Synapse

With the above command I am getting the following error:

> svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/synapse/tags/2.1.0'
>   svn: E175002: The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>    (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/synapse/tags/2.1.0)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue can be resolved by checking out using HTTPS:

> svn checkout https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/synapse/tags/2.1.0 Apache-Synapse

Even though it is mentioned on the web site, it is recommended for developers only.